# How do I get data from a MongoDB collections using node.js and render it as a JSON in expess

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to get data from a `collections` database in my `MongoDB` using `Node`, which I've done successfully. My only problem is how to render the obtained data from the `collections` and posting it into the `express` app.

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const express = require("express");
const app = express()
async function main() {
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://dbUser1:<password>@movies.uxfxv.mongodb.net/Movies?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        let dbo = db.db("Movies");
        dbo.collection("Movies").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            db.close()
        })
    })
}
main().catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Do you want to obtain the Document from `Express`?

Comment: Yeah i would like to as well

Comment: you are getting the documents in the console so now you want to do it from the `Express `right ?

Comment: Yep, btw i solved my own problem by just performing an app.get() in the part were it says  Mongoclient.connect() and the rest is done by logic, it displays now in the express and in postman as  well. Sorry for using your time!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem by just performing an app.get() in the part were it says Mongoclient.connect() and the rest is done by logic, it displays now in the express and in postman as well.

```js
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

const express = require("express");

const app = express()

async function main() {
    
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://dbUser1:<password>@movies.uxfxv.mongodb.net/Movies?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

    MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
    
        let dbo = db.db("Movies");
        dbo.collection("Movies").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            app.get("/", (req, res)     => {res.json(result)})
            db.close()
            
        })
    })
    app.listen(4000, function() {
    console.log("listening to port 4000)
}

main().catch(console.error)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbName = 'test';
const port = 3000;

app.listen(port);

// Type this in your browser to see db data: http://localhost:3000/
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    const client = new MongoClient(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
    client.connect(function(err) {
        console.log("Connected to server.");
        const db = client.db(dbName);
        db.collection("books")
            .find({})
            .toArray(function(err, result) { 
                if (err) throw err; 
                client.close();
                console.log("Done reading db.");
                res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
        });
    });
});
```